# grepping either of the specific formats from a file

Tags: grep

I am trying to extract a text `(ex: Dec 16 16:07:36 2020 GMT)` from a text file.
The text is prepended either by ***UTCTIME:*** or ***GENERALIZEDTIME:***

Now, I can just use `grep -E 'UTCTIME.*GMT'` or use `grep -E 'GENERALIZEDTIME.*GMT'` to get the line from file.

But, I cannot be sure whether the file  has `UTCTIME:` or `GENERALIZEDTIME:`.

So question here, Is there a single command that checks whether the line contains either of those formats and print the line.

I tried something like this `grep -E 'UTCTIME.*GMT\|GENERALIZEDTIME.*GMT'`, but it does not print anything.

Sample format of text.

```
some content
object: signingTime (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
set:
UTCTIME:Dec 16 16:07:36 2020 GMT
some content
```

**OR**

```
some content
object: signingTime (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
set:
GENERALIZEDTIME:Dec 16 16:07:36 2020 GMT
some content
```

Last resort: Even if the command checks `signingTime` and extract the second line from there, but its better to find directly from same line.

Comment: Use `grep -E '(UTC|GENERALIZED)TIME.*GMT' file`

Comment: thanks, dint know its so simple